# connect Python3 notebook to RDS database MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, amazon-rds

I'm struggling to connect my python notebook to my RDS database:

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
    mySQLconnection = mysql.connector.connect(host='mydbtest.ckwrp3e7tutd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
                             database='mydbtest',
                             user='fabio',
                             password='***', port='3306')
    print('Eureka!')

except Error as e :
    print ("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    #closing database connection.
    if(mySQLconnection.is_connected()):
        mySQLconnection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

I already modify the security group to allow any connection and I tested the connection using the terminal:
`mysql -h mydbtest.ckwrp3e7tutd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u fabio -p` and it's working.

The problem is that when I run the above PYTHON3 code i get this error:

```
Error while connecting to MySQL 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mydbtest'
```

This is a screenshot of my RDS database on my AWS console: (PS. is the first time I use it). I also set inbound and outbound connection to "anywhere" on my default security group.

[image: AWS console screenshot]

Comment: use mySQLconnection.close()

Comment: yeah there is an error at the end but this doesn't solve the code not being able to find 'mydbtest': ` Error while connecting to MySQL 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mydbtest' `

Comment: Did you create a database within that MySQL instance called `mydbtest` ?

Comment: Did you make sure that the user account `fabio` is allowed to connect to that database and has the relevant permissions

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated my question to include a screenshot, "fabio" is set as username on the database... and it's working when i connect from shell: " mysql -h mydbtest.ckwrp3e7tutd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u fabio -p "

Comment: OK - Have you created a database within Mysql called `mydbtest` just because the instance starts with that name does not mean there is a database inside MySQL called `mydbtest`. Remember one MySQL instance can contan 100's of seperate databases

Comment: Ok I already hate AWS: so clicking on "create database" does not create a database but an istance that can contain databases? How can I create a database then? .-.

Comment: Oh no way! @RiggsFolly you were right, even if in AWS console there is a button "create database" and in the wizard they always refer to it as a database, apparently is not -.- ... I connected my workbench and created the database, thank you for your help!! :)